# C# Google Or Tools redirect LinearSolver output to string

Tags: c#, stdout, scip, or-tools

I have imlemented several models with Google Or Tools LinearSolver. 
In the backend it's SCIP, that I'm using

If I'm running my application as a Console App, the output goes directly to the console. I have tried setting `Console.SetOut` to a custom 
TextWriter implementation but this didn't seem to work.

My Problem is, that I use the solver in a BackgroundWorker in an ASP.NET Project and need to get the output from the solver while it is solving. (Like a status report about MIP-GAP LB etc.)